Is msinfo32 able to read .nfo files containing indentation?
Question
By default, .XML files labelled as .nfo which are created by msinfo32 on Windows do not contain indentation. Is msinfo32 able to read an .nfo file manually indented using spaces and/or tabs?
Rationale
When sharing the XML files to people who don't use Windows or merely want to find a specific value, it'd be a lot easier to read an indented file.
Paraphrased, as this question revision explains:

You can use as much [whitespace] or as little as you want or need and it will parse correctly. This may or may not change the meaning of the XML document, however.

However, this hasn't been my experience with every tool. I shan't be surprised if msinfo32 is no exception to such noncompliance with the XML specification.
Duplicates
Originally posted erroneously at SO before I answered the question, but since it was a better fit at SU, was moved here per accepted guidance:

My view is that if you have not succeeded in getting an answer in one place, it is fine to cross post and declare that you have done so prominently in the new post, using a hyperlink. That way, people who know the answer can check to see whether they would be duplicating an answer elsewhere before expending effort upon it.


I tested an .nfo file indented with 4 spaces, like the undermentioned:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MsInfo>
    <Metadata>
        <Version>8.0</Version>
        <CreationUTC>05/24/24 14:48:28</CreationUTC>
    </Metadata>
</MsInfo>

Albeit, evidently actual data inside the <Metadata> tags. I didn't indent everything - merely the aforecited <Metadata> tag, and every other tag under the all-encompassing <MsInfo> tags.
This didn't cause any values to not render, but it undeniably did impact the parser, because whilst empty sections should appear empty in the WPF GUI, like the undermentioned:

When indented, they instead displayed something akin to an empty HTML <pre> tag:

Consequently, it indeed parses it, but it parses it incorrectly.
